# google analytics is mixing up my two websites when showing reports

Tags: google-analytics

google analytics is mixing up my two websites when showing reports.  Eg. the top 5 pages include 3 pages from one website and 2 from the other website.?? Can anyone help me, please?

I dont know what to try and I can't find a help page for google analytics

Answer (score 0):

The most common way for this to happen is if your tracking code is present on the both the sites in question (it is possible spam a GA account and achieve the same effect, but as you own both the sites I do not believe this to be the case.).

I suggest:
 - check the audience > technology > network > hostname report. This will tell you all the sites that your code is present on and should confirm that your code is also present on an additional site.
 - check the source code of the other site. Is the code present? look for either GA code or a GTM container. If you're using GTM then check to see whether it is the same container or a different container injecting the same GA code.